# How can i select values from different select types having same class and get their value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am designing select types and check boxes with above code, now i want to get value of each select type and add them and show result in text box.

```
success: function(data) {
  //console.log(data.students);

  var student = "";
  $.each(data.students, function(key, value) {
    student += value +'<input type="checkbox" name="' + value + '" value="' + key + '">Months <select name="amount" class="month" onChange="add();"><option value="">Select months</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="12">12</option></select>';
  });

  student += 'Total Amount <input  type="text" value"" id="total">';
  student += '<button type="submit" > Pay</button>';
  $('#hide').hide();
  $('#student-list').show().html(student);
},
```

and my rest code

```
function add(){

         //var value = ($(this).find("option:selected").text());
      // var value= $("option:selected" ).text();
    //  var  value= $(".option :selected").val();


        var value= $(".month :selected").val();
        sum(value);
        //var val   =$(this).val();
        //alert(value);

    }   

    function sum(value){

        var total=0;

        total=value*1000;

        alert(total);
        //$('#total').val(total);

    }
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this code? It's not clear what you're asking here

Comment: actually i am receiving data from ajax response and after i make dynamic select types and check boxes. now i am trying to get value of each selected type and add their values.

Comment: function add(){

   //var value = ($(this).find("option:selected").text());
      // var value= $("option:selected" ).text();
    //  var  value= $(".option :selected").val();


  var value= $(".month :selected").val();
  sum(value);
  //var val =$(this).val();
  //alert(value);

 } 

 function sum(value){

  var total=0;

  total=value*1000;

  alert(total);
  //$('#total').val(total);

 }

Comment: but i am getting nothing out of it

Comment: that value i get from selected option

Comment: it shows not enough argument

Comment: If you change it to `onChange="add(this)"` then the call should pass in the dom element for the select, which you can then interrogate for it's value.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will work but try

```
$(".month option:selected").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not pass this ?

```
onChange="add(this);"

function add(this){
   var value = this.value; 
}
```